# Conversion into passive voice and order of the words

Tags: passive-voice

This is a sentence in active voice: He cannot rear any cattle on his farm. 
Its passive would be: Any cattle cannot be reared by him on his farm? OR On his farm, any cattle cannot be reared by him? OR Any cattle cannot be reared on his farm by him? Do all the three conversions mean the same thing, does order of words have any effect on the meaning?

Comment: None of these are correct. The [NPI](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) _any_, and its Negative trigger _(can)not_, are the reason. You can't just swap them around any old way -- there are syntactic rules involved besides Passive.

Answer (score 2):

I would render the passive (if you put a gun to my head) as:

> No cattle can be reared by him on his farm.

or

> Cattle cannot be reared by him on his farm.

Comment: Agree about that gun to your head!  But if strictly necessary (or just to satisfy the OP :-), I think your first form is slightly--just slightly--more euphonious.